# update views field value in ajax callback function from other fields

Tags: views, ajax

How can i update drupal views field value without reloading a page. when i execute my ajax callback function i generate some value which is getting save in db. I want to update that value in my drupal view. can anyone help.

```
'#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_approval_status_change_callback',
            'wrapper'  => 'container-inline-'.$reg_id ,
            'progress' => array( 'type' => 'none',  'message' => t('updating')),
        ),
```

This is my callback function. i want another wrapper to be update.

Comment: The field i want to update is different than from where m executing ajax.